# chrome developer tools inconsistent error reporting

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Chrome is reporting 3 page errors in the top right hand side (1), but I am not able to find what those errors are anywhere in the console. Also notice that the console sidebar reports "No errors" (2), and no errors are being displayed on the console

In the attached image,the current console settings have been displayed for extra info

[image]

Could anybody explain what is happening here?
Thanks

Comment: Apparently they are auto-moved into Issues, which is a separate panel.

Comment: did you check the network tab?

Comment: yes, no errors in the network tab

Comment: Is there a public link to this page, which we can check in our consoles?